# How to create custom SAML authentication flow

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-saml

In spring boot I know how to integrate SAML authentication, but I wanted to implement custom authentication on top of spring saml. SAML authentication flow which I wanted to design is like this, when users login it has to check for a key samltoken which is session index if not there it has to redirect to login page. After the login is successful, it has to add a cookie called samltoken(which is having value as session index). For further request saml token key will be there as the user is already login so, for further request I wanted to invoke a REST API by passing samltoken value which is session index. If the response from the REST API is valid the user has to be allowed to access otherwise the should be redirected to the login page. So, how to implement this flow.

Comment: I don't get it. What you're describing is completely standard web application session management, except for the fact that you want your session ID to be called SAML token for some reason.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen by default spring-saml will maintain session but What I want is idp maintained token to be added as cookie(session index which is received from idp) and spring app should be stateless, and if the token is already present in cookie instead of default spring-saml authentication I should call the REST API (this part is the custom implementation)by passing the session index and validate the user.